# Identifying the transitive dependency including a specific library - Gradle

Tags: hibernate, gradle

Does the below statement mean that hibernate core 3.3.2.GA is being overridden by 5.0.11.Final library? I checked this using gradle dependency command. How can identify the transitive dependency that is including this library?

```
org.hibernate:hibernate-core:3.3.2.GA -> 5.0.11.Final
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gradle dependencyInsight --dependency org.hibernate:hibernate-core` to see details for given dependency.